# Get the latest modified file and count lines from modified file

Tags: unix

Trying to write a simple script to find the latest modified file from a directory and then count the lines of that modified file. Below is part of my script.

Note: the `$stg` variable is created for another directory

```
echo "LATEST LOG = $(ls -ltr $stg/abc/foo***.txt | awk '{print $5, $6, $7, $8, $9}' | tail -n1)"
echo "COUNT = $(wc -l $stg/abc/foo***.txt | tail -n1)"
```

What happens on the "COUNT" part is that it does not match the count of the LATEST LOG because it seems to be counting a different log file.

Any suggestions? Thank you!

Comment: Please read [ask] and provide a [mcve].

Comment: FYI, `***` == `*`.  3 times "anything" is still "anything".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suggestion: store the result of the latest log in a variable, and reuse it in the count.  Like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

latestlogline=$(ls -ltr foo*.txt | awk '{print $5, $6, $7, $8, $9}' | tail -n1)
latestlogfilename=$(echo $latestlogline | awk 'NF>1{print $NF}')

echo "LATEST LOG = $(echo $latestlogline)"
echo "COUNT = $(wc -l $latestlogfilename)"
```

Details:

- latestlogline: your code exactly, to extract the complete line of information
- latestlogfilename: just the filename.  `wc -l` expects a filename, so extract it from your first command.
- Then just echo the variable values.
- As commented before, `***` is exactly the same thing as `*`.

Comment: Thank you! This is what I was looking for.

Comment: Follow up question. For the awk part, how to add function to check if file doesn't exist?